# Ejabberd version 17.11 - getting "Failed c2s PLAIN authentication" error message

Tags: ejabberd, erl, ejabberd-auth

I have installed the Ejabberd version 17.11 in our server. After the intallation, the user is able to connect with the Ejabberd service 1st time successfully. But once the session ended by that user and if the same user tries to connect again then we are getting the below error message.

websocket|<0.574.0>) Failed c2s PLAIN authentication for user@domain from xx.xx.xxx.xxx: Invalid username or password

**Note:**
While closing the session by the user we are getting below messages. Is that is the reason for not able to connect after 1st time for the same user?

(websocket|<0.534.0>) Closing c2s session for user@domain/reg_agent: Connection failed: connection closed
[info] Removing any push sessions of user@domain

Answer (score 0):

> [info] Removing any push sessions of user@domain

Looking at the source code file mod_push.erl, that message is logged when the account is being removed.

So, for some reason the account is being removed. If you use anonymous authentication, accounts are removed when they logout. If you use internal or SQL auth, then you should check what other modules you have enabled that may delete an account on logout.

Comment: Now I have commented the mod_push module in ejabberd.yml file and not getting "[info] Removing any push sessions of user@domain" message. But still getting the other below issues.

(websocket|<0.534.0>) Closing c2s session for user@domain/reg_agent: Connection failed: connection closed

websocket|<0.574.0>) Failed c2s PLAIN authentication for user@domain from xx.xx.xxx.xxx: Invalid username or password

Comment: Create a user, then check it exists (using WebAdmin or ejabberdctl), then login, logout, and then see if the accout was removed somehow.

Comment: I tried with lower version 16.06 and I am not facing this issue in that version. But when installed 17.11 or 17.12 then the same issue occurs. Followed the same steps while installing all the versions.

Comment: Interesting tests. Can you install a recent ejabberd 18.06 somwhere to test it too? If the problem still appears, it should be published in a ticket in the ejabberd bug tracker for investigation.

Comment: Getting same issue with the version 18.06 as well. 1st time its opening session with the message. (websocket| Accepted c2s PLAIN authentication for 776145@domainname.com by anonymous backend
(websocket| Opened c2s session for 776145@domainname.com/reg_agent

Once the user disconnected the session then getting message.
(websocket| Closing c2s session for 776145@domainname.com/reg_agent: Connection failed: connection closed

Now user trying to rejoin with the same session and getting error.
(websocket Failed c2s PLAIN authentication for 776145@domainname.com: Invalid username or password

Comment: Ok, then it may be a bug. Let's see if anybody has some idea and comments here, or in the issue ticket https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2566

Comment: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2566
The above ticket is created by myself only.

Comment: After added the below line in .yml config file its working fine now.
auth_use_cache: false

Also, one more thing - Can we use bosh method instead of http_bind method which was used in lower versions. We used this http_bind method for lower version browsers and iPad app which are all not supporting the WebSocket feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my ejabberd.yml file configuration**

```
###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
###


##
loglevel: 4

##
##
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1

##
log_rate_limit: 100

##

hosts:
  - "localhost"
  - "xxxx.xxxx.com"
  - "yyyy.yyyy.com"

##

###.  =================
###'  TLS configuration

define_macro:
  'TLS_CIPHERS': "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH"
  'TLS_OPTIONS':
    - "no_sslv3"
    - "cipher_server_preference"
    - "no_compression"
##   'DH_FILE': "/path/to/dhparams.pem" # generated with: openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
##

###.  ===============
###'  LISTENING PORTS

##
## listen: The ports ejabberd will listen on, which service each is handled
## by and what options to start it with.
##
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
    starttls: true
    ##
    ## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
    ## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
    ##
    starttls_required: true
    ##
    ## Stream compression
    ##
    ## zlib: true
    ##
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
  -
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 131072
    shaper: s2s_shaper

  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: true

  -
    port: 5281
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
    ##starttls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: false

  ##

###.  ==============
###'  AUTHENTICATION

##
## auth_method: Method used to authenticate the users.
## The default method is the internal.
## If you want to use a different method,
## comment this line and enable the correct ones.
##
auth_method: internal

##

host_config:
    "xxxx.xxxx.com":
        auth_method: anonymous
        allow_multiple_connections: true
        anonymous_protocol: both

host_config:
    "yyyy.yyyy.com":
        auth_method: anonymous
        allow_multiple_connections: true
        anonymous_protocol: both

###.  ==============
###'  DATABASE SETUP


###.  ===============
###'  TRAFFIC SHAPERS

shaper:
  ##
  ## The "normal" shaper limits traffic speed to 1000 B/s
  ##
  normal: 1000

  ##
  ## The "fast" shaper limits traffic speed to 50000 B/s
  ##
  fast: 50000

##
## This option specifies the maximum number of elements in the queue
## of the FSM. Refer to the documentation for details.
##
max_fsm_queue: 10000

###.   ====================
###'   ACCESS CONTROL LISTS
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
    user:
      - "xx@xxxx.xxxx.com"
      - "xx@localhost"

  ##

  ## Local users: don't modify this.
  ##
  local:
    user_regexp: ""

  ##

  ##
  ## Loopback network
  ##
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"

  ##

##

###.  ============
###'  SHAPER RULES

shaper_rules:
  ## Maximum number of simultaneous sessions allowed for a single user:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  ## Maximum number of offline messages that users can have:
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  ## For C2S connections, all users except admins use the "normal" shaper
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  ## All S2S connections use the "fast" shaper
  s2s_shaper: fast

###.  ============
###'  ACCESS RULES
access_rules:
  ## This rule allows access only for local users:
  local:
    - allow: local
  ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  ## All users are allowed to use MUC service:
  muc:
    - allow
  ## Admins of this server are also admins of MUC service:
  muc_admin:
    - allow: admin
  muc_log:
    - allow: local
  ## Only accounts on the local ejabberd server can create Pubsub nodes:
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register:
    - allow
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network:
    - allow: all
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## If you enable this you also have to uncomment "s2s_access: s2s"


###.  ================
###'  DEFAULT LANGUAGE

##
## language: Default language used for server messages.
##
language: "en"

#
###.  =======
###'  MODULES

##
## Modules enabled in all ejabberd virtual hosts.
##
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  ## mod_delegation: {} # for xep0356
  mod_disco: {}
  ## mod_echo: {}
  ## mod_irc: {}
  mod_bosh: {}

  mod_last: {}
  ## XEP-0313: Message Archive Management
  ## You might want to setup a SQL backend for MAM because the mnesia database is
  ## limited to 2GB which might be exceeded on large servers
  mod_mam: {} # for xep0313, mnesia is limited to 2GB, better use an SQL backend
  mod_muc:
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access: muc_create
    access_admin:
      - allow: muc_admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    default_room_options:
        logging: true
        persistent: true
    history_size: 0
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  ## mod_muc_log: {}
  mod_muc_log:
     access_log: muc_create
     dirtype: plain
     outdir: "/data/ejabberd/muclogs"
     top_link:
         "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/" : "xxxx.xxxx.com"
  ## mod_multicast: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  ## mod_proxy65: {}
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ## reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    ## XEP compliant, but increases resource comsumption
    ## ignore_pep_from_offline: false
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "hometree"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  ## mod_push: {}
  ## mod_push_keepalive: {}
  ## mod_register:
    ##
    ## Protect In-Band account registrations with CAPTCHA.
    ##
    ##   captcha_protected: true
    ##
    ## Set the minimum informational entropy for passwords.
    ##
    ##   password_strength: 32
    ##
    ## After successful registration, the user receives
    ## a message with this subject and body.
    ##
    ## welcome_message:
    ##  subject: "Welcome!"
    ##  body: |-
    ##    Hi.
    ##    Welcome to this XMPP server.
    ##
    ## When a user registers, send a notification to
    ## these XMPP accounts.
    ##
    ##   registration_watchers:
    ##     - "admin1@example.org"
    ##
    ## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
    ##
    ## ip_access: trusted_network
    ##
    ## Local c2s or remote s2s users cannot register accounts
    ##
    ##   access_from: deny
    ## access: register
  mod_roster: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  ## mod_stats: {}
  ## mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  ## Convert all avatars posted by Android clients from WebP to JPEG
  ## mod_avatar:  # this module needs compile option
  ##   convert:
  ##     webp: jpeg
  mod_version: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_http_api: {}

##
##
## Enable modules management via ejabberdctl for installation and
## uninstallation of public/private contributed modules
## (enabled by default)
##

allow_contrib_modules: true
```

Answer (score 0):

After added the below line in .yml config file its working fine now.

*auth_use_cache: false*

Also, one more thing - Can we use bosh method instead of http_bind method which was used in lower versions. We used this http_bind method for lower version browsers and iPad app which are all not supporting the WebSocket feature.